# Python and IPython paths differ

Tags: python, ipython, bash, .profile

I'm working on a server that I don't have admin privileges to so I've installed packages locally pip --user. In order to get python to see this path I added this to my .profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/delavega/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

This successfully adds locally installed packages to python's path as evidenced by calling sys.path(). However, IPython does *not* use the packages from the local install and instead uses the globally installed package in: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Printing the paths for python and IPython, my local site-packages folder is in both but in different places and the paths overall differ:

Python:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/delavega',
 '/Users/delavega/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

IPython:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/delavega',
 '/Users/delavega/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

As you can see, the paths are different. Appending or prepending IPython's path using sys does not change which package is loaded

Why are these paths different and how can I get IPython to load from my local install?

Comment: What's in your `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`?

Answer (score 0):

The most surefire method to ensure that ipython is virtualenv-aware is to install it with pip into your virtualenv.

There are certainly ipython_config.py hacks (http://rodesia.org/2012/09/04/making-ipython-virtualenv-aware/) to attempt to give it some awareness, but YMMV.